# MVC5 - return custom error doesn't work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

MVC5, c#.net

View makes ajax call to MyAction().
and if error returned has the following 'error' section:

```
error: function (request, status, errorThrown) {

         alert(errorThrown);  // Shows "Internal Server Error" instead of custom error               
        }
```

in Controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> MyAction(string jsonParams)
    {
       try
       {
          ....
           // 'service' is written by another group in our company
           MyClass myObj= await service.myFunction(); // generates exception
          ....
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
        {
             // debugger Does stop here on the break point
             // so it does get here
             return new HttpStatusCodeResult(400, "My Custom error text");              

        }
```

### }

I think Before I used "Task" it worked.
How to show custom error text in this case?

Many thanks

Comment: Use your browser tools (the Network Tab) to inspect the Response which will include the details of the error (an exception might be being thrown before the code in your method is executed)

Comment: It is working fine for me. Can you post your complete code, there might be problem with your code in some other place.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I did add some code points to my post. VS debugger does stop on the line that generates exception and then goes to catch right away;  and does stop on HttpStatusCodeResult  line.

Answer (score 0):

Set async true when ajax call

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/test/test2",
    data: postData,
    async: true
 });
```

Comment: Ajax is by default async (true), so really there is no point in doing this.

Comment: Yes "By default, all requests are sent asynchronously (i.e. this is set to  true by default). If you need synchronous requests, set this option to false."